# String.replaceAll() and \n line breaks

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I try to explain my problem with a little example.
I implemented version 1 and version 2, but I didn't get the desired result. Which replacement-parameter do I have to use to get the desired result with the [replaceAll](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method ?

Version 1:

```
String s = "TEST";
s = s.replaceAll("TEST", "TEST\nTEST");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> TEST
>
> TEST

Version 2:

```
String s = "TEST";
s = s.replaceAll("TEST", "TEST\\nTEST");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> TESTnTEST

Desired Output:

> TEST\nTEST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [javadoc of `String#replaceAll(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see [`Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)). Use
>   [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

```java
s = s.replaceAll("TEST", Matcher.quoteReplacement("TEST\\nTEST"));
```

You still need 2 backslashes, as `\` is a metachar for string literals.

---

You can also use 4 backslashes without `Matcher.quoteReplacement`:

- you want one `\` in the output
- you need to escape it with `\`, as `\` is a metachar for replacement strings: `\\`
- you need to escape both with `\`, as `\` is a metachar for string literals: `\\\\`

```java
s = s.replaceAll("TEST", "TEST\\\\nTEST");
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `replaceAll()`!

`replaceAll()` does a *regex* search and replace, but your task doesn't need regex - just use the plain text version `replace()`, *also* replaces *all* occurrences.

You need a literal backslash, which is coded as two backslashes in a Java String literal:

```
String s = "TEST";
s = s.replace("TEST", "TEST\\nTEST");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
TEST\nTEST
```